# Unit Testing an And16 Logic Gate

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, boolean-logic

I have a javascript representation for both a And and And16 logic gate:

```
function and(a, b) {
    return a && b;
}

function and16(input) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output.push(and(input[i].a, input[i].b));
    }
    return output;
}
```

However, I am not sure that I am testing it properly:

```
describe("And Gate", function() {
    it("returns 1 when both arguments are 1", function() {
        expect(and(true, true)).toBe(true);
    });
    it("returns 0 when both arguments are not 1", function() {
        expect(and(true, false)).toBe(false);
        expect(and(false, true)).toBe(false);
        expect(and(false, false)).toBe(false);
    });
});

describe("And16 Gate", function() {
    it("returns an array of 16 bits that have And applied", function() {
        var sample1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            sample1.push({ a: true, b: false });
        }
        var result1 = and16(sample1);
        for (var j = 0; j < result1.length; j++) {
            expect(result1[j]).toBe(false);
        }
    });
});
```

I am comfortable with the "And" test but for "And16" I am not really sure what I should be testing. Should a test even be required for this? Another thing that does not feel right is that there is a lot of code in the test. Is this a problem?

Comment: Regarding code size, this would certainly be less redundant:  `function and(a, b) { return (a===true) && (b===true); }`

Comment: Yes, nice one. I have updated the code.